# When using a specific browser for ui automation testing, the browser cannot be opened properly for testing

Tags: playwright

```
test('basic test1', async () => {

  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    executablePath: 'path/to/my/browser.exe',
    ignoreDefaultArgs: true
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev")
});
```

When I pass the executablePath and set ignoreDefaultArgs to true, my browser will open normally, but the instantiation browser is waiting

However, when I do not pass in the value ignoreDefaultArgs, the browser does not open and is prompted that the browser is closed;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyZ5Y.png)

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible code example- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I must ignore both --remote-debugging-pipe and --no-startup-window to open the browser normally, but ignoring remote-debugging-pipe will cause the instantiation process to keep waiting